Is this set countable for any function?
Working with CH I order ($\prec$) $^\omega\omega$ of order type $\omega_1$. I let $$f_\alpha:=\min_\prec\{f\in\hspace{1mm}^\omega\omega:\neg (f(n) \leq f_\beta(n)),\forall n\in\omega,\beta\in\alpha\}$$ and $F:=\{f_\alpha:\alpha \in\omega_1\}$. Thus i have a set of size $\mathfrak{c}$ such that
$$|\{f\in F:f(n)\leq g(n),\forall n\in\omega\}|\leq \aleph_0$$
for all $g\in\hspace{1mm}^\omega\omega$.
I can see why it is countable for $f\in F$ since in order for an another function to be below it, it must have been chosen before it, and therefore be in an initial segemnt of $\omega_1$ and thus countable.
Why is it also countable for $g\not\in F$?

And if $g$ isn't in $F$ we know that it is smaller than some $f_\beta$. Being smaller is transitive.

What does $\neg(f(n)\le f_\beta(n)),\forall n\in\omega,\beta\in\alpha$ mean? Is it the same as $\forall n\in\omega\forall\beta\in\alpha\neg(f(n)\le f_\beta(n))$? Why do you write $\neg(f(n)\le f_\beta(n))$ instead of simply $f(n)\gt f_\beta(n)$? Why doesn't your definition imply that $f_\alpha(n)\gt f_\beta(n)$ whenever $\beta\lt\alpha$? What am I missing?

The pointwise $\leq$ is not a total order. For example $\neg (1_{{0}} \leq 1_{{1}})$ but $1_{{0}}$ isn't bigger than $1_{{1}}$.
